# Front end is very slow to render after alt-tab

Tags: front-end, system-performance

I've installed Mathematica 11.1 on my Arch Linux system, but the GUI is very slow to render in after alt-tabbing away (and is just sluggish in general). [Here's a gif which shows what I mean.](https://gfycat.com/EmbellishedUnhealthyAxisdeer)

I'd be happy to allocate more resources to the UI, but I can't seem to find an options for doing so. It doesn't seem to be maxing out my CPU or RAM, so I don't know why it would be so sluggish. How can I fix or troubleshoot this issue?